# What causes this "maximum call stack size exceeded" error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on a **Vue 3** and Bootstrap 5 app. I needed a date-picker and I choose **[Vue 3 Datepicker](https://icehaunter.github.io/vue3-datepicker/)**.

In `components\Ui\Datepicker.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <datepicker
      @selected="handleSelect"
      v-model="dateSelected" 
      :upper-limit="picked_to"
      :lower-limit="picked_from"
      class="datepicker text-center" />
</template>

<script>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    export default {
        setup() {
        const dateSelected = ref(new Date());
        return {dateSelected}
        },

        methods: {
           handleSelect() {
             this.$emit('setDate')
           }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In `components\Ui\Navigation.vue` I have:

import Datepicker from './Datepicker'

    export default {
        inject: ['$apiBaseUrl'],
      name: 'Navigation',
      components: {
            Datepicker,
        },

        data() {
        return {
          // more code
        }
      },

        methods: {
            setDate() {
        this.$emit('setDate');
            }
      },
    }

In `components\Content.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="d-sm-flex>
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

      <Navigation
        @setDate='setDate'
      />
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from './Ui/Navigation'

export default {
  inject: ['$apiBaseUrl'],
  name: 'Content',
  components: {
    Navigation,
  },

  props: {
    title: String,
  },

  emits: ['setDate'],
  
  data() {
    return {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },

     from: '',
     to: '',

    }
  },

  methods: {
   sendData() {
    this.axios.post(`${this.$apiBaseUrl}/submit`, this.fields, {options: this.headers}).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.code == 200) {
      this.isReport = true;
    }
    }).catch((errors) => {
      this.errors = errors.response.data.errors;
     });
    }
   },
    setDate() {
      console.log('Date');
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

#### The problem

Although I select a date from the datepicker, the `setDate()` method is not executed. The Chrome console shows instead:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

##### Where is my mistake?

Comment: This is usually an infinite loop, like you're emitting an event, it triggers an action, but the action emits an event, it's triggers an action etc...

Comment: @kissu is right. If you can't figure out what causes the loop, please create a minimal working version of your code on stackblitz or codesandbox. It will help us easier to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have mentioned previously, the error usually occurs when having an infinite loop.
As Kissu pointed out this can easily happen if you have an event that is emitted to a parent component which then changes data that is passed as props to a child component which then triggers an event to the parent and so on.

In the code you showed I can't really find any loops, they might be in the parts you omitted.

Edit:
The infinite loop could actually be caused by the naming of your component.
You're using `<datepicker ...>` inside `Datepicker.vue` without registering the Datepicker of `vue3-datepicker` there *explicitly*.
That probably causes vue to recursively try to mount the component in itself causing the maximum stack trace error, but that's just a guess.

But there's a couple issues in your code still.

First off:

```
<template>
  <datepicker
      @selected="handleSelect" // <-- according to the docs there are no events that the datepicker emits
      v-model="dateSelected" 
      :upper-limit="picked_to" // <-- where does the picked_to value come from?
      :lower-limit="picked_from" // <-- where does the picked_from value come from?
      class="datepicker text-center" />
</template>

<script>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    export default {
        setup() {
        const dateSelected = ref(new Date());
        return {dateSelected}
        },

        // do not mix options & composition api
        methods: {
           handleSelect() {
             this.$emit('setDate')
           }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You're mixing options and composition API, which is never a good idea.

There's also a couple values that seemingly come from nowhere and you're listening to a `@selected` event from the datepicker, which according to the [docs](https://icehaunter.github.io/vue3-datepicker/#props-and-attributes) doesn't exist, so you'll have to watch for changes in the selected date yourself.

The same component in the composition API would look like this:

```
<template>
  <Datepicker v-model="initialDate" class="datepicker text-center" />
</template>

<script>
import Datepicker from "vue3-datepicker";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";

export default {
  components: { Datepicker },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const initialDate = ref(new Date());

    watch(initialDate, (newDate) => {
      emit("setDate", newDate);
    });

    return { initialDate };
  },
};
</script>
```

I tried to recreate the example you gave in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-vue3-datepicker-q3dpnh?file=/src/components/Datepicker.vue:0-420) and I do not encounter any infinite loop issues.

You might wanna check it out and compare with your code and possibly fix all the other issues first and see if that helps your situation :)

Comment: How do I get the _set date_ out of there?

Comment: Which set date do you mean exactly? Can you point me to the line? :)

Comment: When dates are picked, `this.from` and `this.to` should get their values from the Datepiker instances.

Comment: What should I do if I need to use _two_ instances of the date picker in the _Navigation_ component?